# Ruby On Rails [Carrierwave]: Cannot delete image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm a newbie in rails and trying to implement image uploading to ftp with 'carrierwave-ftp' gem. For image uploading, I have two controllers. First one is 'events_controller' while the second one is 'events_pictures_controller'.

Pictures are getting uploading to ftp. But the problem is that when I'm deleting a single picture, it is destroying the entire event. Please help!

Here is my Events Model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_pictures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_pictures, allow_destroy: true
  validates_presence_of :name, :date
end
```

Here is my EventPictures Model:

```
class EventPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :picture_title, EventPicturesUploader
  validates_presence_of :picture_title
  belongs_to :event, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Events Controller:

```
def index
    @events = Event.all.order('date DESC')
end  

def show
    @event_pictures = @event.event_pictures.all
end

def new
    @event = Event.new
    @event_picture = @event.event_pictures.build
end

def edit
end

def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @event.save
          params[:event_pictures]['picture_title'].each do |a|
            @event_picture = @event.event_pictures.create!(:picture_title => a, :event_id => @event.id)
          end
      format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
    @event = Event.find params[:id]
    @event.destroy
    redirect_to events_url
end

private
  def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:name, :date, event_pictures_attributes: [:id, :event_id, :picture_title])
  end
```

This is the Destroy method in EventPictures Controller

```
def destroy
    @event_picture = EventPicture.find params[:id]
    @event_picture.destroy
    redirect_to "events_url"
end
```

Meanwhile in the events.show.html.erb, I have this:

```
<% @event_pictures.each do |p| %>    
      <%= link_to image_tag(p.picture_title_url, :class => 'event-img'), image_path(p.picture_title_url) %>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', p, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just try removing `dependent: :destroy` from this: `belongs_to :event, dependent: :destroy` in `EventPicture` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `EventPicture` model you have `dependent: :destroy` on the association which means that when the picture will deleted the corresponding events too. So just edit the association and make it:

```
belongs_to :event
```

And you have dependent destroy on the `Event` model so when a event will be deleted the corresponding pictures too will get deleted which is correct.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error lies with this line

```
belongs_to :event, dependent: :destroy
```

This is telling the EventPicture model to delete its parent model Event when it is deleted.

Replace with

```
belongs_to :event
```

Comment: Yes this was the issue, problem solved. Thank You very much